# how to loading file .jrxml in page jsp with liferay?

Tags: jasper-reports, liferay

I want to display jasper report on jsp page .How i can do ?
I try this code but it not work and get some problems :

```
    String jrxmlFile = "D://Data_DuongNgocThanh//BaoCao557//report1.jrxml";
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));
    System.out.println("Load lan 1");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(),new JREmptyDataSource());
    System.out.println("Load xong roi");
    //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, OutputStream("sample.pdf"));
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    response.getOutputStream().close();
```

**Error**

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /view.jsp at line 38

**Error Line :**

> ```
>   JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
> ```

I need another way or solution for this .

**update:**

```
06:42:54,980 ERROR [PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:108] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /view.jsp at line 42

39:         String jrxmlFile = "D:/Data_DuongNgocThanh/BaoCao557/report1.jrxml";
40:         InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));
41:         System.out.println("Load lan 1");
42:         JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
43:         JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(),new JREmptyDataSource());
44:         System.out.println("Load xong roi");
45:         //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, OutputStream("sample.pdf"));


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /view.jsp at line 42

39:         String jrxmlFile = "D:/Data_DuongNgocThanh/BaoCao557/report1.jrxml";
40:         InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(jrxmlFile));
41:         System.out.println("Load lan 1");
42:         JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);
43:         JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(),new JREmptyDataSource());
44:         System.out.println("Load xong roi");
45:         //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, OutputStream("sample.pdf"));
```

Comment: i update  my question .

Comment: You don't need to mark an update in your post (SO maintains a post history). And that is not the _stacktrace_. You should check your log, there should be something with many `at ...`